# pgadmin4 6.19 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

Since the very last (at the time of writing) [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) upgrade (from `6.18` to `6.19`) in [its Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/), I'm facing an this issue when spinning up the container from scratch: `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'username'`

Here are the complete docker logs during startup between those two versions:

- 6.18:

```bash
pgadmin4  | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin4  |
pgadmin4  | pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
pgadmin4  | ======================================
pgadmin4  |
pgadmin4  | ----------
pgadmin4  | Loading servers with:
pgadmin4  | User: postgres@localhost
pgadmin4  | SQLite pgAdmin config: /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
pgadmin4  | ----------
pgadmin4  | Added 8 Server Group(s) and 31 Server(s).
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:05:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:05:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:5050 (1)
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:05:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:05:01 +0000] [94] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 94
```

- 6.19:

```bash
pgadmin4  | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin4  |
pgadmin4  | pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
pgadmin4  | ======================================
pgadmin4  |
pgadmin4  | ----------
pgadmin4  | Loading servers with:
pgadmin4  | User: postgres@localhost
pgadmin4  | SQLite pgAdmin config: /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
pgadmin4  | ----------
pgadmin4  | 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'username'
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:08:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:08:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:5050 (1)
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:08:45 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin4  | [2023-01-17 14:08:45 +0000] [92] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 92
```

The problem occurs both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Any hint on how to solve this?

Because now, the `servers.json` file with my 8 configured server groups doesn't seem to be taken into account anymore when I spin up the container, and I end up with an empty server list:

[image]

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading to v. `6.20`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known issue in 6.19. Fix will be available in 6.20 release.
Currently you use daily snapshot build..
Alternatively, you can import/export servers options from UI. Tools > Import/Export Servers. Refer to [link](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.19/import_export_servers.html).

Comment: Tracker is here: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5751

Comment: Thanks for that piece of information; I wasn't sure if I missed something or else. I will wait for the next release then.